# Same code, different result css?

Tags: html, css

Hei 
I might be sleepy or something is really missing and i am not getting it.
Doing a tutorial(clock), coding all, not copy paste nothing and the second handle is in a different position than the original. check, recheck, can´t find anything different that can change it. The actual code works if i just copy paste.

My code:

```
    html{
    background: #018DED url(http://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=50);
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'helvetica neue';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

body{
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 2rem; /*ver a diferença que faz a seguir com o html*/
     display: flex;
     flex:1;
     min-height: 100vh;
     align-items: center;
}

.clock{
    width:30rem;
    height: 30rem;
    border:20px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto;  /*centra*/
    position: relative;
    padding: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 
      0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
      inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF,
      inset 0 0 10px black,
      0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.clock-face {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    transform: translateY(-3px);  /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand {
    width:50%;
    height:6px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
}

------------------------
tutorial code

   html {
      background:#018DED url(http://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=50);
      background-size:cover;
      font-family:'helvetica neue';
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

body {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 2rem;
      display:flex;
      flex:1;
      min-height: 100vh;
      align-items: center;
    }

.clock {
      width: 30rem;
      height: 30rem;
      border:20px solid white;
      border-radius:50%;
      margin: 50px auto;
      position: relative;
      padding:2rem;
      box-shadow:
        0 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
        inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF,
        inset 0 0 10px black,
        0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

.clock-face {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translateY(-3px); /* account for the height of the clock hands */
    }

.hand {
      width:50%;
      height:6px;
      background:black;
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
    }
```

---

```
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clock</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clock.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-face">
      <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mind giving us the HTML here, as well as the working vs. not working CSS?

Comment: Sure .i thought could be something there. but i don´t change the html from one code to the other, and with one works with the other don´t...<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Clock</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clock.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-face">
      <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
    </div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can You update Your question with HTML code as well?

Comment: @zolv just put it

Comment: @RicardoMoreira you're missing debugging 101: copy/paste only 50% of it. Then split the faulty half into half. And again. You can break down thousands of lines in a matter of minutes with this technique and you have here like... what? 30 lines? Please read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). And the accepted answer. When you find the answer, if you don't understand why it's happening, even though you read the docs on the property, than you have yourself a valid question and [so] will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing semicolon.

Here :

```
.clock-face {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% // Missing semicolon here
    transform: translateY(-3px);  /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}
```